# Running unit tests in multiple assemblies using nunit-console

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I would like to run the fast tests in all the test assemblies in one go, to get a convenient unified output.

My current batch file looks like this, it runs the tests: but many of the tests fail (they pass when the assemblies are specified individually). I suspect this is due to an inability to access the app.config required for some of the tests.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set myvar="d:\path-to-nunit\nunit-console-x86.exe"
for /r D:\path-to-root-of-working-copy\ %%i In (*.Test.Unit.dll) DO set myvar=!myvar! "%%i"
set myvar=!myvar! /domain=Multiple /framework=net-4.0
call %myvar%
```

Can anyone think of any possible problems with my approach? I am investigating and will update the question as I find more.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of NUnit (and referencing it in *all* solution projects) fixed the issue.